# if I use yarn Error: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

Until just now, yarn ran well, but suddenly a strange error started to appear.

If i use this command,

`yarn run dev`

Bus error: 10

`yarn -v`

Segmentation fault: 11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW4Uk.png)

I tried reinstalling yarn and reinstalling the brew, but the results were the same